# values keep looping

Tags: java, sql, database, jsp, foreach

This is what I did. I want to get the stockid, stock name and stockprice under each . But unfortunately, it keeps on looping. What I means is that, it suppose to only have S0001 XXX 19.90 but instead it is having S0001 ABC 19.90, S0002 ABC 19.90, S0003 ABC 19.90, S0004 ABC 19.90. Then it will go back to S0001 and ABC will change to the next value in my database. This means that my stockname loop 4 times while my stockprice loop 12 times.

```
    <sql:setDataSource url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/healthdb;user=nbuser;password=nbuser" driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"  
                       var="Derbydata"/>  
<sql:query sql=" SELECT stockid FROM STOCKS" dataSource="${Derbydata}" var="STOCKS" />
<sql:query sql=" SELECT stockname FROM STOCKS" dataSource="${Derbydata}" var="STOCKS1" />
<sql:query sql=" SELECT stockprice FROM STOCKS" dataSource="${Derbydata}" var="STOCKS2" />
 <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>
                 Stock ID   
                </th>
                <th>
                Stock Name    
                </th>
                <th>
                    Stock Price
                </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                         <c:forEach var="row3" items ="${STOCKS2.rowsByIndex}">
                             <c:forEach var="row2" items ="${STOCKS1.rowsByIndex}">
                             <c:forEach var="row1" items="${STOCKS.rowsByIndex}">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                 <c:out value="${row1[0]}"/>
                    </td>

                    <td> 
                        <c:out value="${row2[0]}"/>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${row3[0]}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Your queries and foreach logic looks really wrong to me.

Comment: You appear to be issuing 3 queries. You should be issuing *one* query for all three fields that you want to display.

Comment: make it SELECT * FROM STOCKS

Comment: As Jon mentioned, you should use a single query, the result of this query is a cursor. Loop through this cursor and for each field, extract the value from each row in the cursor.

Comment: So, row and column ?

Comment: Think of row in your JSP table as a row in database, that is returned by the select * from stocks; You have 3 columns in your database, respectively you should have 3 columns in your table. For each column in your table you should display the corresponding value from each column in your db table.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the query to the field wanted and use index or 0 1 2 ....

```
<sql:query sql=" SELECT stockid,stockname,stockprice FROM STOCKS" dataSource="${Derbydata}" var="STOCKS" />
                       <c:forEach var="row1" items="${STOCKS.rowsByIndex}">
            <tr>  
                <td>
             <c:out value="${row1[0]}"/>
                </td>
                <td>             <c:out value="${row1[1]}"/></td>

                <td>             <c:out value="${row1[2]}"/></td>

            </tr>
```